# PhoneGap Build and SoundCloud Embed code

Tags: angularjs, soundcloud, phonegap-build

I have embedded SoundCloud playlist snippet in my PhoneGap application and all I see is a blank space where the player should be.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" 
 src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/12345678&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true">
</iframe>
```

Has anyone had success embedding the playlist player in PhoneGap?

Comment: i am not a cordova/pg developer, but you have ensured you can access w.soundcloud.com and api.soundcloud.com etc.? http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_access_elements.md.html

Comment: You need to read the docs. You need to add the [white-list](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide). Make sure you set the version for your phone-version and the plugins, or you will get the latest version. If you do not set the version, you will need to use the `white-list plugin` too.